# Need to match user ids from two fields to their names in another table

Tags: php, join, matching, names

I am working on some stuff for my game server and making a custom site ban.

I have a ban table (ban time, reason, banned player, banning admin, etc) The banned player and banning admin field both use player ids which are stored in the other table.

I know how to join tables but I can't figure out how to distinguish between the banned player and the admin, the tables are basically like:

info table:

```
some info field| more info | more info| player_id | creator_id

info info      | info info | info info|         1 |          2
info info      | info info | info info|         3 |          2
info info      | info info | info info|         5 |          4
```

players table:

```
id  | name

1   | john
2   | steve
3   | sally
4   | bob
5   | jack
```

The player id is the player that was banned and the creator is the admin, all names whether admin or player are all stored in the players table. What I want is to have a page that shows the banned player, the reason for ban, the banning admin and the time

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the tables are in an RDBMS like Postgres or MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try :

```
SELECT
  info1,
  info2,
  p1.name AS player_name,
  p2.name AS admin_name
FROM more_infos mi
JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = mi.player_id
JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = mi.creator_id;
```

## see [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e45e/2) with Demo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to the players table twice - once for the banned user (player) and once for the creator of the ban (admin), like so:

```
SELECT info.*, player.name, admin.name
FROM info
JOIN players player ON player.id = info.player_id
JOIN players admin ON admin.id = info.creator_id
```

Comment: Thanks! @blankspac3, if this was helpful to you I would appreciate it if you would mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT j1.name banned_player, j2.name admin
FROM info_table it
JOIN players j1 ON j1.id = it.player_id
JOIN players j2 ON j2.id = it.creator_id
```

Give that one a try.